# Is Java's java.util.Random reliable?

Tags: java, random, mersenne-twister

I cannot help but notice...after I have started developing my math game (and gave it to beta-testers after constantly tweaking it, and I am still not done!) that my use of `java.util.Random` and its method `nextInt()` casted to double may not be the reliable saviour class I was looking for. Is it for generating random numbers for applications like mine? //The point of this app is to make an arithmetic game that is challenging for ALL PEOPLE and lets you solve problems with both integer and floating-point arguments. The highest number my program generates is a 6-digit number, and that is because of some different logic I have used for the Human Calculator (highest level) difficulty, namely for the division problems. I was thinking about using Mersenne twister algorithm, but I think the algorithm used by `java.util.Random` is something like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29 .

Also, I would like to know if it would be recommended that I use something like `new java.util.Random(System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: ....define "reliable" ?

Comment: you can also use java.util.UUID

Comment: I believe you should not use `new java.util.Random(System.currentTimeMillis())` since the seed will be limited to a millisecond (or even larger) resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Random`'s no-arg constructor is already based on the current time (through its cpu nanoTime and not the UTC date) so just creating it will get you a different seed every time. the seeded `Random(long)` version is (in my experience) mostly used when you want predictable output (some procedural generation routines for computer games, for example, allow the player to specify a random seed)

if youre very worried about how random your random numbers are, you might want to look at [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), which is recommended over plain Random for encryption and such. there's a nice explanation of how to use it [here](https://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/) and a VERY good explanation of the difference between the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have this pretty covered, particularly mfrankli's answer regarding the difference between statistically random and cryptographically random.  In your situation, you really only need the latter, so `java.util.Random` is good enough.

All that being said, one easy mistake to make (which has bitten me at least once), is creating many `Random` instances within a short period of time.  For example calling `new Random()` every time you need a random number.  You should initialize `Random` once and re-use it as much as possible.  Since `Random` is seeded off the system time (even at a the nano scale), the output of a series of `Random` instances created at very close to the same time will not be uniformly distributed.

Comment: and your suggestion is exactly what I did!

Comment: +1 for pointing out *"one easy mistake"* ..which I've personally made, and corrected 100+ times since then.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, `java.util.Random` should be fine for your application; and simply using the constructor `new java.util.Random()`, with no argument, should also be fine.

Longer answer: `java.util.Random` is *not* cryptographically secure - there's a technical definition here, but essentially it isn't 'random enough' for security people to feel safe using it; an attacker could potentially guess the random numbers produced. However, it satisfies two other important properties:

1. Resembles the random distribution i.e., each value is equally likely to be generated.
2. Non-deterministic i.e., you'll get a different sequence of values each time.

In other words: you should be good to go.