# Generate secure random number uniformly over a range in Java

Tags: java, security, random

How do I generate a **secure uniform** random number within a range? The range could be between 0 to 100. (The upper bound is not a power of 2).

[`java.security.SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) seems to provide the range `0..2^n`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do

```
Random rand = new SecureRandom()
// 0 to 100 inclusive.
int number = rand.nextInt(101);
```

or

```
// 0 inclusive to 100 exclusive.
int number = rand.nextInt(100);
```

Note: this is more efficient than say `(int) (rand.nexDouble() * 100)` as nextDouble() needs to create at least 53-bits of randomness whereas nextInt(100) creates less than 7 bits.

Comment: I just removed my comment, as it was wrong. Sorry guys.

Comment: Yep. That's my bad really :( Need to learn to read docs more carefully.

Answer (score 9):

Try below code snap

```
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    int max=50;
    int min =1;

    System.out.println(random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min);
```