# How to generate Random numbers using SecureRandom

Tags: java

I have the below code which uses `java.util.Random`, now I want to change to `java.security.SecureRandom`. How do I do the same operations with SecurRandom?

```
int rand = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    rand = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    switch (rand) {
        case 0:
            c = '0' + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            break;
        case 1:
            c = 'a' + (int) (Math.random() * 26);
            break;
        case 2:
            c = 'A' + (int) (Math.random() * 26);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a took at [Generate secure random number uniformly over a range in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742702/generate-secure-random-number-uniformly-over-a-range-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`secureRandomObject.nextDouble()` is essentially equivalent to `Math.random()`

So following code will work...

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
int rand = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    rand = (int) (secureRandom.nextDouble() * 3);
    switch (rand) {
        case 0:
            c = '0' + (int) (secureRandom.nextDouble() * 10);
            break;
        case 1:
            c = 'a' + (int) (secureRandom.nextDouble() * 26);
            break;
        case 2:
            c = 'A' + (int) (secureRandom.nextDouble() * 26);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `nextDouble` when you want an `int` in the end?

Comment: @Thilo Kindly check http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Math.java#Math.random%28%29

Comment: Thats because `Math.random()` essentialy calls `nextDouble`.

Comment: For this specific case `int` would work. But its not a exact replacement of `Math.random()`

Comment: A `downvote` seems pretty harsh on this one. An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
int rand = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    rand = random.nextInt(3);
    switch (rand) {
    case 0:
        c = '0' + random.nextInt(10);
        break;
    case 1:
        c = 'a' + random.nextInt(26);
        break;
    case 2:
        c = 'A' + random.nextInt(26);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't mean to say it was you. But left the comment in case the downvoter sees this comment on top.

Answer (score -1):

Do you wish to achieve something like this :

```
    int rand=0,c=0;;
SecureRandom secrnd=new SecureRandom();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    rand = (int) (secrnd.nextInt(10)% 3);
    switch (rand) {
    case 0:
        c = '0' + (int) (secrnd.nextInt(10) % 10);
        break;
    case 1:
        c = 'a' + (int) (secrnd.nextInt(10) % 26);
        break;
    case 2:
        c = 'A' + (int) (secrnd.nextInt(10) % 26);
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Please clarify your question , so that i can understand what you want to achieve with the above code.