# How to generate Random point(x,y) in Java

Tags: java, math

I want to generate a random point(x,y) in java which should lie within a 2D plane {(1,1)(1,-1)(-1,1)(-1,-1)} where both positive & negative X & Y axis is considered.Thank you

Comment: You create two random floating point values between 0 and 1; and then you randomly multiply with -1. All of that is really basic stuff that you can look up within minutes using your favorite search engine

Comment: How about use new Random().nextFloat()?

Comment: Also, please specify what you mean by "random". Which probability mass function should be used?

Comment: thank you @ Wietlol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_random.htm. All you need to do is to generate pairs of floats in range (-1,1). You should use method nextFloat() from class Random. It will give you numbers in range (0,1). Then multiply it by 2 and subtract 1 and you will have numbers in desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) see: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom)

Answer (score -1):

Use this method below to return you the random points

```
public String randXYPoint(){
    //For x and y, the maximum point is 1 and Minimum point is -1
    //maximum number
    int min = -1;
    //minimum number
    int max = 1;

    // generates x values
    double xValue = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    // generates y values
    double yValue = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    //returns and converts points to string 
    return  String.valueOf(xValue)+ ", "+ String.valueOf(yValue);
}
```

Just call the method

```
System.out.println(randrandXYPoint())
```