# Java Random Password generator issue

Tags: java

So I need to know is there a way to show the final password of this code to jTextField control, cuz when I tried I got issue char couldnt convert to String.

```
import java.util.Random;

Random r = new Random();

String alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    System.out.println(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
}
```

Comment: `charAt` returns a `char`, if you want a string use `"" + char` or something equivalent

Comment: Do not use pseudo-random generators where security is important. Their behaviour is deterministic and can lead to security leaks.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do how doesn't it work?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently in your code you are just generating the characters randomly and printing it. You need to form a `String` from all these generated Characters and then you can set it as a Text in a `TextField`.

You can have a `StringBuilder` which gets appended with every random `character`.

```
String alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
StringBuilder password=new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    password.append(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
} 
String password_str=password.toString();
System.out.println(password_str);
```

Suppose that you have a `JTextField` then you can set there password_str as its value.

```
JTextField password_field = new JTextField();
password_field.setText(password_str);
```

Comment: `Random` should not be used for password generation.

Comment: @gonczor I have pointed the mistakes @SteveYo has made And that's what asked in the question. He didn't ask about `How to generate more secure password` And I According to me, This `50` letters long password does provide a good security!

Comment: Length of a password has nothing to do with security if you can predict the sequence. And what approach is this that you can leave a code with such security risks just because someone has not asked for reviewing this part?

Comment: Length of a password is what makes a password strong. If you have a password of `50` letters and all possible letters are `26` then Total possibilities will be `26^(50)` which is a very big number and with BruteForce its difficult to get broken. Now if length is around `200` then total possibilities are `26^200`. Can you see the difference?

Comment: And can you understand that I am not talking about brute-forcing it?

Comment: But how do you measure a security of any algorithm or any encryption algorithm?

Comment: The state of pseudorandom generator can be determined in far less than this 26^50 steps. Please go through this at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom

Answer (score 1):

```
    Random r = new Random();

    String alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        buf.append(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
    }
    jTextField.setText(buf.toString());
```

Comment: Please use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) for password generation.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes: SecureRandom is much better

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to provide secure random-generated password use [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) with proper methdos. Please refer to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141715/how-to-determine-the-state-of-a-random-number-generator). I do not have any articles about it in english, but if you could get on with some translator please read [this one](https://sekurak.pl/obliczanie-stanu-generatora-liczba-pseudolosowych-na-przykladzie-math-random-z-firefoksa/) to see how one could hack such algorithm.

EDIT:

[More on difference between `Random` and `SecureRandom`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051205/difference-between-java-util-random-and-java-security-securerandom)