# Generate 8 digit OTP in java

Tags: java, android

Generate 8 digit OTP in java with first digit as zero.
I have tried with `Math()` function in Java but it gives random numbers first digit without zero.
Suggest me an easiest way to achieve the same

Comment: generate a 7 digit one and add a zero as first digit (there is no `Math()` function in standard Java)

Comment: Its difficult to maintain the length if you are adding zero as first letter. Using format, you can do this.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters i had a request for 8 digit OTP with 0 as the first digit. even though it is marked as duplicate

Comment: @YogeshivuN you marked an answer as accepted that did nothing but point to the other question. *You and your colleague together made this a duplicate*.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `SecureRandom`. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052736/1776132

```
String.format("%08d", new SecureRandom().nextInt(10_000_000))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static final LENGHT = 8;

Random randomizer = new Random();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(i = 0; i <= LENGHT; i++) {
   builder.append(randomizer.nextInt(10));
}

String otp = builder.toString();
```

**EDIT**

As Smile mentioned, using [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) would be better choice.

```
static final LENGHT = 8;

SecureRandom randomizer = new SecureRandom();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(i = 0; i <= LENGHT; i++) {
   builder.append(randomizer.nextInt(10));
}

String otp = builder.toString();
```

If you want first digit as zero always;

```
static final LENGHT = 7;

SecureRandom randomizer = new SecureRandom();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("0");
for(i = 0; i <= LENGHT; i++) {
   builder.append(randomizer.nextInt(10));
}

String otp = builder.toString();
```