# Should SecureRandom be used as singleton or a new object should be created each time random number is generated?

Tags: java, random, secure-random

I am using `SecureRandom` to generate random numbers.

Does it make any difference with respect to predictability of next number generated if the `SecureRandom` object is a singleton or a new object is created every time a random number is generated?

*Singleton:*

```java
public RequestIdGenerator {
    private static SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

    public static int generateRequestId() {
        secureRandom.nextInt(100_000_000);
    }
}
```

**vs.**

*New object for each time random number is generated:*

```java
public RequestIdGenerator {

    public static int generateRequestId() {
        new SecureRandom().nextInt(100_000_000);
    }
}
```

This question arose after reading about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052736/1776132) related to 'Predictability of Linear Congruential Generators'.

Comment: Why downvoted ?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference (although much of `SecureRandom` is platform specific), but that shouldn't matter since the first way is the correct way and the second way would be the horribly wrong way.

Comment: @Kayaman if it shouldn't make a difference, why is the second horribly wrong?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca because `SecureRandom` is an expensive object to create unnecessarily, so whereas it shouldn't affect the predictability (although it might drain the entropy, not sure, [guess not](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40633/java-securerandom-doesnt-block-how)) it's still an obviously wrong way to use a long lived object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should SecureRandom be used as singleton or a new object should be created each time random number is generated?

You should not create many `SecureRandom` instances.  It is expensive, and liable to drain your system's source of entropy (randomness).

If you run out of entropy, the `SecureRandom` creation is liable to block in a syscall ... waiting ... for ... more entropy to be harvested.

> Does it make any difference with respect to predictability.

It should not make any difference to predictability.  If you treat a seeded  `SecureRandom` as a black box, it should not be possible to predict the next number *unless* you know the seed and the previous history of the generator.

The caveat is that a *flawed implementation* of a secure random number generator may not actually be secure.  (But the flipside is that the entropy you are using to generate seeds may not be as random as you think ... either.)

> This question arose after reading about ... 'Predictability of Linear Congruential Generators'.

LCGs are fundamentally not secure.  You could not use one for a `SecureRandom` implementation.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) includes references to the requirements for any `SecureRandom` implementation.  If you have practical concerns, read the references.