# How to obtain all possible values returnable by Random.nextLong?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

The [Random#nextLong()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong--) documentation states that this method will not return all possible `long` values:

Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed long value from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of `nextLong` is that one long value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. The method `nextLong` is implemented by class Random as if by:

```
public long nextLong() {
    return ((long) next(32) << 32) + next(32);
}
```

Because class Random uses a seed with only 48 bits, **this algorithm will not return all possible long values**.

For example, the number `8090327796378429294` is generatable, but the number `8090327796378429295` is not, even though their only difference is one least significant bit, and the value itself is 63 bits long.

There's a way to know whether or not a value can be returned by `nextLong()` using the following algorithm:

```
public class JavaRandom {
    private static final long ADD = 0xBL;
    private static final long MULT = 0x5DEECE66DL;
    private static final long TWO16 = 1L << 16;
    private static final long MASK_31 = (1L << 31) - 1;
    private static final long MASK_32 = (1L << 32) - 1;
    private static final long MASK_48 = (1L << 48) - 1;

    public static boolean canBeGeneratedByJavaRandom(long randomValue) {
        long i1 = (randomValue >> 32) & MASK_32;
        long i2 = (randomValue & MASK_32);
        if (i2 > MASK_31) {
            i1 = i1 + 1;
        }

        long front = i1 << 16;
        for (long i = 0; i < TWO16; i++) {
            long seed = front | i;
            long i22 = (((seed * MULT) + ADD) & MASK_48) >> 16;
            if (i22 == i2) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I get all values that can be generated by `nextLong()` without running this check for every possible 64-bit number? Calling `nextLong()` until all values are collected doesn't feel reasonable as well as there can be collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the [`setSeed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed-long-) function fully uses the lower 48 bits of the value passed in to set the seed, you can simply iterate over all `seed` value from `0` to `(1L << 48) - 1`, `setSeed` to each of them, then call `nextLong()` once for each seed.

More info:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052736/5267751) points out that it's possible to determine the seed from 2 consecutive `nextInt()` values, therefore there are no two different seeds that generates the same 2 consecutive `nextInt()` values.
- The documentation states that `nextInt()` calls `next(32)`, and `nextLong()` gets the value of 2 consecutive `next(32)` values.

From the two points above, different seed values will generate different `nextLong()` values.